# Unity Android Build not running after split apk and split binary

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine

I exported an android build of my app using unity to android studio where I build a release and debug versions of the app. The output was split by target architecure(x86, armeabi and arm64). 3 apks for release and 3 for debug. An obb file was also generated after exporting next to the android studio project. I copied the apk and named it to playstore standards(main...obb) then installed all apks but none seem to load beyond the first scene. Ive tried with various devices but none seem to work. What should I do to fix it? All help is appreciated.
Note:I also build an android apk bundle :D . Please have a look at these screenshots
[Debug builds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eSz0.png)
[Release builds and obb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TDnb.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Are You sure You have included your needed scene in build?

You can do it by clicking "Add Open Scenes"

[image: Build window]

2. If scene is present in build , your initial script could crash in runtime so You need to check it with Android Monitor (wich is present with Android SDK https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor)